# C# Script Using StreamWriter Creates Extra Character?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, bids

I am using a C# Script Tasks in SSIS to output ASCII characters. I am doing this because I am creating a file with Packed fields, a packed field takes two digits into each byte, using a notation called Binary Coded Decimal.

So, I have found when outputting a NUL (0x00) [Dec 0] with a Œ (0x8C) [Dec 140] it adds an extra character Â (0xC2) between them. I can't figure out why this is happening. Does anyone have any ideas? Please see my code below:

```
string fileName;
System.IO.StreamWriter writer;

public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();

    this.fileName = this.Variables.FilePath;
}

public override void PostExecute()
{
    base.PostExecute();
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
}

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    writer.Write((char)00);
    writer.Write((char)140);

    writer.Write((char)13);
    writer.Write((char)10);
}
```

Output below:

[image: ExtraCharacter]

**UPDATE**
One thing I didn't make a point of is that I am passing Hex Values into the C# Script and then writing the Characters represented by the hex value to a file with fixed length columns.

I don't know if this makes a difference, but I will also be writing other things to the file that aren't the packed values on the same lines as the packed values, and thus the reason for using the StreamWriter.

Comment: What encoding is your writer using? My guess here is that it's an UTF8 escape sequence.

Comment: Values in BCD will not consistently be within the ASCII range, why aren't you using a `BinaryWriter` for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an encoding issue.
It shouldn't happen if you write *byte*s.

```
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(someStream);
write.Write((byte)123); // just an example! not a "that's how you should do it"
```

A better solution would be to select the proper encoding. But does the way your characters look in the file really matter?

Comment: Yes, it does matter, what characters are in the file. The file I am generating has fixed lengths and adding an extra character causes the fields to have incorrect values and to be longer than they should.

Comment: Then using a charset with variable character length is not a good choice. One approach would be to use the ASCII charset, which uses exactly 7 bits for every character (last one is always 0). If you want to use additional characters which are not supported, you can add another 128 using the 8th bit.

Comment: Writing a byte like you have shown doesn't actually output an ASCII Character for the value 123. It just writes 123 to the file. This will cause the values within the file to be incorrect.

Comment: I suppose you should be using a BinaryWriter then. I'll edit my answer. Give me one minute. // Done - But still, you should not use that code for your purpose. Specify the proper encoding and you shouldn't have any more problems.

Answer (score 3):

A `StreamWriter` is for writing **text** to a stream. It always uses an encoding and if you don't specify one when you create it it will use UTF-8 (without a byte order mark - BOM). The output you get is the UTF-8 encoder trying to translate the the text (in the form of individual characters) into UTF-8.

If you want to write **bytes** to a stream simply write to the stream directly using the `Write` method that accepts an array of bytes. If you want to write to a file you can create a `FileStream` and use that as the stream.

The naming of classes within the `System.IO` namespace can be confusing at times:

- `Stream` is an abstract base class providing methods to read and write bytes
- `FileStream` is a `Stream` that reads and writes to a file
- `BinaryWriter` allows you to write primitive types in binary form to a `Stream`
- `TextWriter` is an abstract base class that allows you to write text
- `StreamWriter` is a `TextWriter` that allows you to write text to a `Stream`

You probably should use `FileStream` or `BinaryWriter` on top of a `FileStream` to solve your problem.

Comment: Do you think you could provide a sample or a link to a place using a BinaryWriter on top of a FileStream? I have tried using a BinaryWriter as suggested but it add weird character to any strings I output.

Comment: @buzzzzjay: `BinaryWriter` has overloads to write many primitive types to the stream including an overload to write strings. This overload will encode the strings (again using UTF-8) if you don't specify it yourself. In your case I think you should use the overload to write a single byte to the stream.

Comment: I have BinaryWriter overloading FileStream:  
FileStream fs = File.Create(@"C:\buzzzzjay.txt");
UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs, utf8);
bw.Write("String Test"); It writes the string to the file as expected, but also adds (VT) 0x0B hex value at the begging of the string. So "(VT)String Test" is in the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. I had to convert the string to a byte[] array so that it wouldn't generate special characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must have not specified the correct encoding of your writer.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72d9f8d5.aspx

and: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx